# Android: How to make application invisible to task managers and in the menu

Tags: android, hidden

I would like to develop an application which runs as a **background service**. Once it gets installed, it can be controlled **remotely** by **control messages**. I don't want the application to be shown on the menu or the task list. Any help is appreciated. Any alternate ideas are appreciated as well.. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All running services are shown on the running services list under applications.  I seriously hope you *CAN NOT* hide them.

Icons do not need to appear on the main application menu.  You can remove the icon from appearing on this menu by not defining an icon/label in your manifest.

Your request sounds sketchy/shady.

Comment: Yes, I don't want it to be hidden from running services. But Some applications can hide from Task Managers. I wanted to know how to do that. They just run in the background as a service.

Comment: A task manager might monitor applications and/or services.  You would have to define how the task manager worked prior to evaluating how to hide from it.

Comment: The task manager lists only running applications and not services. If this is the case, then how to hide?

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like you want a Remote Service in conjunction with Cloud to Device Messaging or some other push solution. If you want your service to start on boot, register it with a broadcast receiver for android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED.

There's a good tutorial on remote services here: http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/RemoteService.html

And cloud-to-device messaging here: http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/index.html